# VBA Open Workbook from Macro fails "(path & filename) could not be found. Check the spelling..."

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, which should simply open a workbook from a master workbook to allow me to paste some information which I will later retrieve from a database. I receive the error in the title **every time** I try to open a workbook. I have used similar code before with no problem at all. The files are kept on a server away from my desktop, but the path has been correct each time. I've checked over and over again. What could be the culprit?

```
Sub copyDealerDataToWorkbook(ByVal targetID As Integer)

    Dim mainWB      As Workbook    
    Dim directory   As String
    Dim fn          As String
    Dim aFile       As Excel.Application

    Set aFile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
    directory = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    'append a "\"
    If InStrRev(directory, "\") < Len(directory) Then
        directory = directory & "\"
    End If

    fn = targetID & ".xls"

    aFile.Application.Visible = True
    aFile.Workbooks.Open directory & fn 'ERROR ON THIS LINE
    aFile.Parent.Windows(1).Visible = True
End Sub
```

I have also tried the following code...

```
Sub copyDealerDataToWorkbook(ByVal targetID As Integer)
    Dim foreignWB   As Workbook
    Dim mainWB      As Workbook
    Dim directory   As String
    Dim fn          As String

    Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
    directory = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    'append a "\"
    If InStrRev(directory, "\") < Len(directory) Then
        directory = directory & "\"
    End If

    fn = targetID & ".xls"

    Set foreignWB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=directory & fn) 'ERROR ON THIS LINE
End Sub
```

Comment: First, Do you mean to have the <br /> in the variable declarations? Second, can you tell me what your directory string is returning?

Comment: Of course not... excuse the first post. directory string returs "\\Oesdfiles\Users\FName LName\Reports\test_data\monthly EDS reports\Number by dealer Per importer\test_2011\2011-01January" I can also run Application.FileSearch and find the file with that directory and filename combination... so I'm really at a loss.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  Are you sure the extension is ".xls" ?

Comment: Isn't that related to a full name length > 255 ?

Comment: Hmm... Good guess, but the directory path is only 123 chars long, so the file name would have to be 132 chars long... unlikely.

Comment: Just a remark: `aFile` is already an `Application` object, so `aFile.Visible` is same as `aFile.Application.Visible`  is same as `aFile.Application.Application.Application.Application.Visible`... so might as well stick to the short version: `aFile.Visible = True`. Just saying! Also, since you're using early binding, you should probably stick to that notation and write `Set aFile = New Excel.Application` instead of `CreateObject`.

Comment: Have you tried printing `directory & fn` to make sure the `\` gets added properly?

Answer (score 0):

First use hard code with name of file and test if is open.

For sample

```
Workbooks.open "\\Oesdfiles\Users\FName LName\Reports\test_data\monthly EDS reports\Number by dealer Per importer\test_2011\2011-01January\YourFileHere.xls"
```

If Yes, your directory or fn var is wrong.

If No, try use office diagnostic in office button/ excel options/Resources/Diagnostic

And try again.

If not work's , your excel need's reinstall.

[]'s

Answer (score 0):

```
If Dir(directory & fn) <> "" Then
    'do the magic
Else
    MsgBox "Directory and file not found:" & vbCrLf & directory & fn, vbCritical, "Invalid Directory"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
targetID As Integer
```

This only works if your Excel workbook has a numeric file name without leading zeroes.  Also, In this context there's no need to make targetID an Integer since you aren't iterating or performing calculations on the value, I would make it instead:

```
targetID As String
```

Edit:  I just realized this was posted 2 years ago.  :P